# Issue working with parse - object cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

I am trying to populate a page with information about user such name, age and profile picture from parse. In attempting so, I have encountered some issues such as:
Along with formatting errors such as
[image]
, I am encountering the following issue:

1) object cannot be resolved

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
        String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
    }

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<String> age;
    private ArrayList<String> headline;
    private ArrayList<String> activityname;

    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber(
            "Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
            "Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        age = new ArrayList<String>();
        headline = new ArrayList<String>();
        activityname = new ArrayList<String>();

        alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>();

        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");




        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users,ParseException e) {

                // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");

                ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


                ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                 // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
                 // data.
                 imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
                 imageView.setParseFile(image);
                 imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                     Log.i("ParseImageView",
                         "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                   }


             });
            }
        });

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistname.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
                }
            });

        }
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistheadline, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistheadline.size(); i++) {
                        headline.add(userlistheadline.get(i).get("Headline")
                                .toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistheadline);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_all,
                            headline);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done2(List<ParseUser> userlistage, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistage.size(); i++) {
                        age.add(userlistage.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistage);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            age);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done3(List<ParseUser> userlistactivity, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistactivity.size(); i++) {
                        activityname.add(userlistactivity.get(i)
                                .get("ActivityName").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistactivityname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            activityname);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Update
I have added another picture
[image]

Comment: it appears you brackets are messed up and you have an extra one

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. which one in particular, and what about the object issue i have which is my biggest problem?

Comment: Hello, can you give us log error

Comment: Hi Allel, unfortunatetly i cant give you a log error cause i cant run it due to errors. I am a bit confused, and any suggestions could help'

Comment: It seems like you've just messed up the bracket scopes as the underlines are specifically under the scopes which is indirectly returning you that weird error, just -/+ a bracket there and all is fine

Comment: I added another picture under the update section of my initial post

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post enough code to show where the missing or extra bracket is. Just go through your code carefully, work your way outward, collapsing methods etc as you go.

Comment: thanks for your response and advice, i posted the entire activity code, but i guess thats insuffcient.  what about the object issue i have which is my biggest problem?

Comment: i added another picture under the update section of my initial post

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have something like below to iterate over the list:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects,ParseException e) {

for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
                // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");

                ParseFile image = objects.get(i).getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


                ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                 // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
                 // data.
                 imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
                 imageView.setParseFile(image);
                 imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                     Log.i("ParseImageView",
                         "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                   }


             });
            }
}//for loop
        });
```